# Why is the sequential layer expecting 3 dimensions in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Upon trying to train my LSTM network, I am given the error: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, None]`.

My code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

numFeatures = 26; #amino acids
numClasses = 64; #codons
x_test = tf.ragged.constant(XTest)
y_train = tf.ragged.constant(YTrain)
y_test = tf.ragged.constant(YTest)
x_train = tf.ragged.constant(XTrain)

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(26, 10), ragged=True),
        layers.LSTM(128,use_bias=False),
        layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
    ]
)

model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer="adam",
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)
model.fit(
    x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), batch_size=5, epochs=1
)
```

model.summary() shows me this:

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 128)               70656     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 71,946
Trainable params: 71,946
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-ae3b9eb7daa0> in <module>()
     15 )
     16 model.fit(
---> 17     x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), batch_size=5, epochs=1
     18 )

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:531 train_step  **
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:886 __call__
        self.name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:180 assert_input_compatibility
        str(x.shape.as_list()))

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, None]
```

Comment: You are being confused by the "layer sequential_9", this is the name of a layer, not of your Sequential model. I think it refers to your LSTM, use model.summary() to confirm. So the problem is that Embedding produces 2D output if you did not set input_length, while LSTM requires 3D input.

Comment: Ah, @Dr. Snoopy, that may be it. Will investigate, thanks!

Comment: Hmm, @Dr.Snoopy, model.summary() shows the model name is sequential_9, and the error is still ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_9 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, None]

Comment: Then include the full traceback and the output of model.summary()

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, thank you.

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is with your training data, in particular the shape of x_train and x_test, are these 3D arrays?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy 
[list([1,2,3,4])
list([1,2,3,4,5,6])
list([1,2,8,4,5,7])]

This is a small representation of what my x_train & x_test looks like. The y_train is similar, except with strings, rather than integers.

Comment: I am talking about the shapes, not the values. It should have a 3D shape like (batch or samples, timesteps, features)

Comment: x_train: TensorShape([40000, None])
x_test: TensorShape([2266, None])

Comment: So I said, LSTMs take 3D input, a time series, you do not seem to have timeseries data?

Comment: Yes, that is correct! There is no time involved, however, the data is sequential. Any pointers on what I should instead do? A little bit of context: I trained this same dataset in MatLab using a BiLSTM, so I assumed it would operate in a similar manner using Keras & Tensorflow.

This is a little bit more of a natural language processing task, and such.

Comment: If its a sequence of one-dimensional data, then the shape can be (samples, sequence or time steps, 1), as you would only have one element per timestep or sequence dimension.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218638/discussion-between-rishab-jain-and-dr-snoopy).